# Union two list of dates, union with further info

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables of dates, for the questions's sake call them `dates1` and `dates2`. Sometimes a given date is in both, sometimes it is in 1 but not 2, and other times in 2 but not 1.

My original requirement was just a list of *all* dates from both sets

```
SELECT Date FROM dates1
UNION
SELECT Date FROM dates2
```

Easy peasy. New requirement; know which list the dates came from (or both if that is the case). The columns I need are as follows:

```
Date, IsList1, IsList2
```

So, some example data:

```
Dates1
======
Date
====
2017-01-31
2017-02-28
2017-03-31

Dates2
======
Date
====
2017-01-31
2017-04-30
```

Expected output

```
Date       | IsList1 | IsList2
2017-01-31 | 1       | 1
2017-02-28 | 1       | 0
2017-03-31 | 1       | 0
2017-04-30 | 0       | 1
```

SQL fiddle with the above data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/5425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll most likely need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and some expressions to achieve this.

```
SELECT ISNULL(D1.[Date], D2.[Date]) AS [Date],
       CASE WHEN D1.[Date] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsList1,
       CASE WHEN D2.[Date] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsList2
FROM @dates1 D1
     FULL OUTER JOIN @dates2 D2 ON D1.[Date] = D2.[Date];
```

It's also worth nothing, on your SQL fiddle, that you have 2 `INSERT` statements into `@Dates1` and none into `@Dates2`, thus the result set is `1` for all of `IsList1` and `0` for `IsList2`.

Comment: Any reason to use `ISNULL` rather than `COALESCE`?

Comment: Old habit more than anything @DavidG. `COALESCE` works fine as well.

Comment: Fair enough, `COALESCE` always "felt" better to me in this sort of situation, particularly if you have more values, but I don't know if perf is any different between the two.

Comment: I don't believe there's any benefit to using `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` in this circumstance, @DavidG . That isn't, however, to say that they're synonyms. `COALESCE` for example can take more than 2 parameters, whereas `ISNULL` can only take 2. `COALESCE` is also actually just an abbreviated `CASE` expression, whereas `ISNULL` is not. As such, `SELECT ISNULL('A',1);` is perfectly fine, as `1` is converted to a `varchar` (the first parameter's type), whereas `SELECT COALESCE('A',1);` will fail, as `'A'` can't be converted to an `int` (due to data type precedence, and that it is `CASE` expression).

Comment: It's also worth noting that for `ISNULL` the function will fail if the **second** parameter cannot be converted to the first (this is not the case for the other way round, as seen in my prior comment). For example: `SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(int,NULL),'A');` will fail. Of course, that'll also fail using `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte
as
(
select dt.date as tb1,dt1.date as tbl2
from
@dates1 dt
full join
@dates2 dt1
on dt.date =dt1.date
)
select isnull(tb1 ,tbl2 ) as dt,
case when tb1 is  not null then 1 else 0 end as list1,
case when tbl2 is  not null then 1  else 0 end as list2
from cte
```

Comment: `isnull(dt.date as tb1,dt1.date as tbl2)`? That isn't valid syntax. Also, the OP wants the value `0` not a *`NULL`* when it isn't in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another option with a simple aggregation:

```
Select Date
      ,InList1=sum(InList1)
      ,InList2=sum(InList2)
 From (
        Select Distinct Date,InList1=1,InList2=0 from @dates1
        Union All
        Select Distinct Date,InList1=0,InList2=1 from @dates2
      ) A
 Group By Date
```

Returns

```
Date        InList1 InList2
2017-01-31  1       1
2017-02-28  1       0
2017-03-31  1       0
2017-04-30  0       1
```